# how to customize material ui icon by adding plus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, material-ui, icons

I'm using material ui icons, is there any way to add plus to icons ?

This is my icon :

> import ApartmentIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Apartment';

[image]

and that icon should have plus to it like here:

[image]

I have been trying to find a way but did not find anything,
these are icons i want plus to them:' CameraAlt,
Apartment,
Web,
Assessment,
Description,', any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sx` property here is what you need.

```
<Box sx={{ background: "black" }}>
  <Box sx={{ position: "relative", display: "inline", color: "white" }}>
    <CameraAltOutlinedIcon sx={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
    <AddIcon
      sx={{
        position: "absolute",
        right: "-5px",
        bottom: "2px",
        color: "black",
        fontSize: 22,
        strokeWidth: "6",
        stroke: "black"
      }}
    />
    <AddIcon
      sx={{
        position: "absolute",
        right: "-6px",
        bottom: "1px",
        color: "white",
        fontSize: 22
      }}
    />
  </Box>
</Box>
```

I had to use two 'plus' svg AddIcons one inside the other with some stroke to the one on the back to act like a frame for the one on the front and have a better looking result.
The only thing you need to do is adjust the left/right attributes depending the main icon you are using and the colors to match your background.

Here also is a  [working codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/svgiconssize-demo-material-ui-forked-6b5yrl?file=/demo.tsx:247-934)

Comment: it seems to work but i'm not using react 18 and i'm not using '@mui' but im using '@material-ui' could you possible make that work with these settings here: https://codesandbox.io/s/svgiconssize-demo-material-ui-forked-4ewg4h?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: @walee 'mui' stands for 'Material-ui' and the version of React has not effect at all. Have you tried the solution? Also the codepen I sent you is forked from material-ui docs. You can just copy the content from the <Box> tag and should work for you. The sandbox you sent me is not working

Comment: at the moment when making width larger it takes whole width, i mean ' background: "black"', how to make background color just for that icon and not whole width of window ?

Comment: The outer <Box> with the black background was for the demo purposes to add contrast and see the result. Use the <Box> inside it I updated the sandbox to help you understand what I mean.

Comment: project i'm working on uses older material ui, and not this new mui, when using your code with older material ui, i am getting an icon and two plus next to it, is it because new mui uses Emotion as style and older material ui uses something else ? i have those dependencies in link i provided

Comment: project i'm working on uses older material ui, and not this new mui, when using your code with older material ui, i am getting an icon and two plus next to it : https://codesandbox.io/s/svgiconssize-demo-material-ui-forked-4ewg4h?file=/Demo.tsx

Comment: @walee I will update the answer using another way to achieve this using styled components. I have also updated your sandbox with the working solution, I only installed the styled components library. If you don't have it in your project you either can install it, or you can move the css attributes in css classes of your own.
Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/svgiconssize-demo-material-ui-forked-17b4gu?file=/Demo.tsx:622-756

Comment: i wanted this same thing but with alphabet letters, since material ui doesnt have it i used different in my new question, could you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237034/replacing-material-ui-icons-with-material-design-icon

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the icon you are looking for

import AddAPhotoIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddAPhoto';

Comment: these are i want plus to them ' CameraAlt,
  Apartment,
  Web,
  Assessment,
  Description,'

Comment: i cant find plus for those others, so then what to do ?

Comment: you can try react-icons package but the best solution for this would be create svg icons using figma

Comment: @razer if you don't want to add another library which again might not have all the icons you are looking, try using from MUI the icon you want and the plus icon as two separate svgs. To do it you can have a container with relative position then add you icon inside it and the 'plus' icon with absolute position and smaller font-size. If you are interested in this approach and you find any difficulties let me know and i can send you the code

Comment: @Akis hey you will save my day with it, could you do that to this and show me how you did it: import ApartmentIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Apartment

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using styled components:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core/";
import { CameraAlt } from "@material-ui/icons";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import styled from "styled-components";

const IconContainer = styled(Box)`
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
`;

const PlusIconBack = styled(AddIcon)`
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  bottom: -1px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 21px;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: black;
`;

const PlusIconFront = styled(AddIcon)`
  position: absolute;
  right: -7px;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
`;

function Demo() {
  return (        
    <IconContainer>
      <CameraAlt />
      <PlusIconBack />
      <PlusIconFront />
    </IconContainer>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

The point of it, is to use a container giving it position `relative`, add your main icon, then add your plus icons with position `absolute` and place them where you want using left/right top/bottom.
Sandbox: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svgiconssize-demo-material-ui-forked-17b4gu?file=/Demo.tsx:168-917)