# replacing material ui icons with material design icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui icons, here i have camera icon which has another icon connected to it(AddIcon), i want to have icon for each letter in alphabet but material ui doesnt have it, so i found 'materialdesignicons' which has alphabets.
My question is how to replace that plus (addicon), for example with 'b' alphabet of 'materialdesignicons'  ?

my code:
codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/svgiconssize-demo-material-ui-forked-yfs77g?file=/index.tsx:73-134

code:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";

import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import CameraAltOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CameraAltOutlined";
export default function SvgIconsSize() {
  return (
    <Container sx={{ background: "black", height: "100vh" }}>
     
      <Box // This is your container
        sx={{
          position: "relative",
          display: "initial",
          color: "black", //  camera icon takes the fill color from here
          width: "50px", 
          height: "50px"
        }}
      >
        <CameraAltOutlinedIcon sx={{ fontSize: 40, color: "white" }} />
        <AddIcon // This acts like a frame for the plus icon for a good looking result
          sx={{
            position: "absolute",
            right: "-6px",
            bottom: "1px",
            fontSize: 22,
            strokeWidth: "4",
            stroke: "white"
          }}
        />
        <AddIcon // This is plus icon
          sx={{
            position: "absolute",
            right: "-6px",
            bottom: "1px",
            color: "black", //  plus icon takes the fill color from here
            fontSize: 22
          }}
        />
      </Box>
      {/* UNTIL HERE */}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

this is what i want to use: import { mdiAlphaB } from '@mdi/js';

so i checked tutorial : https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started/react

but i would just get rotating 'b'

it should look like this

[image]

but instead of plus, there should be 'b'
Any suggestions ?

Comment: any idea is appreciated

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Did you try `<Icon path={mdiAlphaB}>` with `Icon` imported (`import Icon from '@mdi/react'`)?

Comment: @Bqardi yes here: https://codesandbox.io/s/svgiconssize-demo-material-ui-forked-0oh6ir?file=/demo.tsx:127-136

Comment: Replace `sx` with `style`

Comment: @Bqardi still it doesnt look like the one i want (it should look cuz we just changed icon nothing else)

Comment: They are two different components, so difference in layout is expected. I can't and won't try to guess what you expect it to look like.

Comment: @Bqardi i have provided link to what it should look like to: https://codesandbox.io/s/svgiconssize-demo-material-ui-forked-yfs77g?file=/index.tsx:73-134          just instead of plus should be 'b'

Comment: Try changing the properties, for example change `fontSize: 22` to something like: `width: "28px"`

Comment: Haven't investigated, but my guess is that the "old way" uses fonts while the "new way" uses `svg`'s

Comment: @Bqardi changing sx to style and also fontsize from 22 to 28 helped, if you want please like my question it would help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first install material design icons by running command

```
npm install @mdi/react @mdi/js
```

after that import like so

```
import Icon from '@mdi/react'
import { mdiAlphaB } from "@mdi/js";   // The icon to use
```

and then replace this

```
<AddIcon // This is plus icon
          sx={{
            position: "absolute",
            right: "-6px",
            bottom: "1px",
            color: "black", //  plus icon takes the fill color from here
            fontSize: 22
          }}
        />
```

with

```
<Icon   //B icon
          path={mdiAlphaB}
          title="User Profile"
          size={2}
          color="white"
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: "15px",
            top: "-10px"
          }}
        />
        )
```

and at the end tweak `position` property a bit if needed. And voila! you are done. [link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svgiconssize-demo-material-ui-forked-nl0xsc?file=/demo.tsx)